# hash search in linked list using C linux

Tags: c, linux, search, hash, linked-list

Hi I am searching a linked list using hash search. My linked list contains about 3500 random numbers with values ranging from 10000 - 1000000. I have never used hash search before but this time I am given this assignment. So I have to do it. Please see my code and correct me. It's a bit lengthy but please, because I need it badly now. I have been trying to do it since last 6-7 hours.

```
struct entry_s 
{
    int *key;
    int *value;
    struct entry_s *next1;
};

typedef struct entry_s entry_t;

struct hashtable_s
{
    int size;
    struct entry_s **table;
};

typedef struct hashtable_s hashtable_t;


/* Create a new hashtable. */
hashtable_t *ht_create( int size )
{
    hashtable_t *hashtable = NULL;
    int i;
    if( size < 1 ) 
    return NULL;

/* Allocate the table itself. */
    if( ( hashtable = malloc( sizeof( hashtable_t ) ) ) == NULL )
    {
            return NULL;
    }

/* Allocate pointers to the head nodes. */
    if( ( hashtable->table = malloc( sizeof( entry_t * ) * size ) ) == NULL )
    return NULL;

    for( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
            hashtable->table[i] = NULL;
    }
    hashtable->size = size;
    return hashtable;
}
/* Hash a string for a particular hash table. */
int ht_hash( hashtable_t *hashtable, int *key )
{
    unsigned long int hashval;
    static int i = 0;
    hashval += i;
     return hashval % hashtable->size;
}

/* Create a key-value pair. */
entry_t *ht_newpair( int *key, int *value ) 
{
    entry_t *newpair;

    if( ( newpair = malloc( sizeof( entry_t ) ) ) == NULL ) 
    return NULL;
    if( ( newpair->key = key ) == NULL )
    return NULL;
    if( ( newpair->value =value ) == NULL ) 
    return NULL;
    newpair->next1 = NULL;
    return newpair;
}

/* Insert a key-value pair into a hash table. */
void ht_set( hashtable_t *hashtable, int *key, int *value )
{
    int bin = 0;
    entry_t *newpair = NULL;
    entry_t *next1 = NULL;
    entry_t *last = NULL;

    bin = ht_hash( hashtable, key ); 
    next1 = hashtable->table[ bin ];
    while( next1 != NULL && next1->key != NULL && key==next1->key  > 0 )
    {
            last = next1;
            next1 = next1->next1;
    }

 /* There's already a pair. Let's replace that string. */
    if( next1 != NULL && next1->key != NULL && key== next1->key  == 0 )
    {
            free( next1->value );
            next1->value =value;
    } 
    else 
    {
            newpair = ht_newpair( key, value );
            if( next1 == hashtable->table[ bin ] )
            {
                    newpair->next1 = next1;
                    hashtable->table[ bin ] = newpair;
            } 
            else if ( next1 == NULL )
            {
                    last->next1 = newpair;
            } 
            else 
            {
                    newpair->next1 = next1;
                    last->next1 = newpair;
            }
    }
}

/* Retrieve a key-value pair from a hash table. */
char *ht_get( hashtable_t *hashtable, int *key ) 
{
    int bin = 0;
    entry_t *pair;

    bin = ht_hash( hashtable, key );

/* Step through the bin, looking for our value. */
    pair = hashtable->table[ bin ];
    while( pair != NULL && pair->key != NULL && key==pair->key > 0 )
    {
            pair = pair->next1;
    }

/* Did we actually find anything? */
    if( pair == NULL || pair->key == NULL ||  key==pair->key != 0 ) 
    return NULL;
    else 
    return pair->value;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    hashtable_t *hashtable=ht_create(4000);
    insert1(); 
    for(cur=first;cur!=last->link;cur=cur->link)
    {
        ht_set(hashtable,i,cur->data);
        i++;
    }
    printf("Data inserted into the hash table");
}
```

insert1() is taking data from a text file and putting it in the list.

```
fsll.c: In function ‘ht_create’:
fsll.c:55: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
fsll.c: In function ‘ht_newpair’:
fsll.c:88: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
fsll.c: In function ‘ht_set’:
fsll.c:116: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ht_hash’ makes pointer from integer without     a    cast
fsll.c:125: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
fsll.c:128: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
fsll.c:134: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ht_newpair’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
fsll.c:134: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ht_newpair’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
fsll.c: In function ‘ht_get’:
fsll.c:162: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ht_hash’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
fsll.c:172: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
fsll.c:175: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
fsll.c: In function ‘insert1’:
fsll.c:190: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
```

These are the warnings.
Many THANKS

Comment: Do you have a specific problem and/or question? Is the code working and you´re asking for improvements? ...?

Comment: No, the code is not working. It's getting compiled giving several warnings. and It's giving segmentation fault after inserting data into the linked list

Comment: Then please show cour compiler warnings and detect the line of the segfault with a debugger.

Comment: ‘ht_set’
 passing argument 2 of ‘ht_hash’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: Sorry, i meant: Show "all" of your several warnings by putting them into your question, in a code block, with line numbers and everything. And the debugging results too.

Comment: I have mentioned warnings. I am debugging my code now. and will put them also a bit later. Till then, try to correct something by warnings :)

Comment: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x007469c4 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
This is what debugger showed in main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few remarks on the code

you forgot some includes

```
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc
#include <stdio.h> // for printf
```

You have uninitialised values in your functions, that means the values are unknown and depend on what is stored in memory when created, therefore they are incremented the result is still unknown.

```
unsigned long int hashval;
int i;
```

in ht_set

```
while( pair != NULL && pair->key != NULL && key==pair->key > 0 )
if( pair == NULL || pair->key == NULL ||  key==pair->key != 0 )
```

I don't understand `key==pair->key > 0` and `key==pair->key != 0`, maybe you meant

```
while( pair != NULL && pair->key != NULL && key==pair->key)
if( pair == NULL || pair->key == NULL ||  key==pair->key)
```

in main

maybe I am missing some code but I see no declarations for `cur, first, last`. Moreover your ht_create function seems to set all entries to NULL, therefore, there can be no next. I don't think everything is there, as I don't have all the code I cannot compile it and try to run it.